# Vb.NET Form/datagrid refresh question

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid view control that is tied to a dataset. so when the Dataset is updated with a new record,It shows up in the grid. The problem is, I have to minimise the window or some how force a re-paint on that window to see the updated grid.

Any thoughts on how to call that refresh? Form.refresh and form.grid.refresh did not work.

Comment: Why not just re-bind the dataset with grid again?

Comment: It would nice to see some code on how you are loading the GridView and how you are updating it...reload the GridView immediately after updating the DataSet...Form.Refresh has nothing to do with the GidView.

Comment: GrdExec.DataSource = gdsXXX.tbExec  and then we update the dataset, the grid fails to refresh it unless I minimise the window or force a refresh/repaint

Answer (score 0):

In response to my comment....this was quickly typed up in the editor and wasn't tested, but should give you an idea on how it should be done.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ds as New DataSet

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            'Initial load of the DataSet
            LoadGridView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      'Update the DataSet

      'Then reload the GridView
      ReloadGridView()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGridView()
            ds = 'Fetch the data from the DB and lod into DataSet.
            'Bind DataSet to GridView.
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReloadGridView()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            LoadGridView()
    End Sub
End Class
```